# Adding a New HTML Row to a group inside the HTML table

Tags: jquery

I have the following table structure:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="myRow" class="content">
        <td>Option 1</td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Option 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="altcontent">
        <td>file code 1 </td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="altcontent">
        <td>file code 2</td>
    </tr>

      <tr class="content">
        <td>Option 3</td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Option 4</td>
    </tr>

      <tr class="altcontent">
        <td>file code 3 </td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="altcontent">
        <td>file code 4</td>
    </tr>

</table>

var newContentRow = $("<tr></tr>");
```

I want to add the newContentRow right after Option 2 and Option 4. Of course, this is just an example and there can be many options with many or non file code rows.

Any ideas!

**UPDATE 1:**

I updated my code to the following as suggested below:

```
  var searchClass = "TBLCONTENTS";

    var rows = $("#" + rowId).parent().children("tr");   

    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {


        if ($(rows[i]).attr('class') != searchClass && $(rows[i]).prev().attr('class') == searchClass) {

            $(rowToBeAdded).addClass("TBLCONTENTS");
            $(rows[i]).before(rowToBeAdded);

   }               
   }
```

It even go inside the if check and performs the .before function but I only see the row added to the second group and not the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Loop through each row,
// ... if the current class is different than your desired set,
// ... and the previous row is the same as your desired set,
// ... inject a row before it.

classSet='content';

$('#myTable TR').each( function(){

    if( $(this).attr('class') != classSet && $(this).prev().attr('class') == classSet ){

        $(this).before('<tr class="' + classSet + '"><td>new option</td></tr>');

    }

});
```

Comment: I actually changed this because I got the impression he only wanted to add a new row to sets with a specific class (i.e., "content" and not "altcontent").

Comment: Your code works great if I use <tr> in the before function. If I try to add my own rowToBeAdded then it only adds it one time. I just did rowToBeAdded.clone() and now it works. I guess that was because I was added the jQuery object to a list and you cannot add same object twice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#myTable')
.find('td:contains("Option 2")'
.parent()
.after("<tr><td></td></tr>")
```

You can use any selector like I used `:contains()` to find the row after/before which you need to add a new row. Use `after` method to add a new row after or `before` to add it before the row.

Comment: Option 2 is just an example! It can be anything. I think I need to do something with the class names since they are different.

Comment: Yes you can use any selector to find the row after or before which you have to add the row.

Comment: In your code it will add the new row after each option. I do not want that. I need the new row to be added once in each group of options.

Comment: It will not add new row after each option but after row which contains "Option 2". If you know the class then use class selector.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining clearly! Forget that there is anything in TD. Forget about the text "option". How can I add a new row only once for each group. Option 1 and Option 2 is considered one group so it should add the new row once not twice. Same with option 3 and option 4.

Comment: How do you determine the groups?

Comment: Using the class "content"! I know this is very weird but this is some legacy code. the content class before the altcontent class is considered a group.